# Using Mono to recognize executable files in Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, mono

Can we recognize which file is executable (i.e. `chmod +x`) using Mono under Linux? Is there any method in common .Net/Mono base class libraries?

Edit: **native Linux executables**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best you can do is use the `Mono.Unix.Native` namespace to check file permissions, I believe. You can check whether a file has executable permissions (for owner/group/others) by calling the [`Syscall.Stat`](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=M%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall.stat) method. More specifically, you'll want to look into the [`FilePermissions`](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=T%3aMono.Unix.Native.FilePermissions) enum.

Comment: Small correction. Syscall.Stat - http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=M%3aMono.Unix.Native.Syscall.stat

Comment: And in Windows we can identify executable file by its extension or analyzing its structure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [we can](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/?p=92), but I don't know of a common .NET class that does it. You could look at the mono sources. :)

Edit:

The original link refers to a helper application, which can't be found. However, the Mono Project page has something to say about [binfmt support](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide:Running_Mono_Applications) too, and no helper app seems to be required.

Comment: Unfortunately this link about detecting .Net or Wine executables and source of utility is inaccessible therewith.

Comment: Haha, I just realized I parsed the original question entirely wrong! I read that as which file is (executable using mono) rather than which file is executable (using mono). Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Though it's not exactly a method to find .NET executables, you can load the assembly with `Assembly.Load`. If it fails, it's not a .NET assembly.

Comment: I told about native executables, not .Net assemblies

Comment: OK, the question was a little ambiguous in this regard. I thought it meant that you want to find files that can be executed using Mono under Linux.